# Create Flutter huawei release

Tags: flutter, release, huawei-mobile-services

I have developed the flutter app and already added Huawei configurations. How I create a release build for Harmoney OS using android studio. Please share the steps

Answer (score -1):

I added configuration files and follow the same steps as creating an android APK. It works for me.